# if message contents has a number followed by a letter then do something

Tags: python

I have a script that scrapes some reselling servers. Some people write in the price in the format of 2.1k the issue I am having is I look for the letter "k" and use that in the price but it looks for words with the letter "k" for example a listing will show "Taking 2.1k for my product" It will show the price as "Taking" because of the letter "k". How would I go about making sure it only looks for numbers followed by the letter K?

```
        check1 = False
        check2 = True
        for x in message.content.lower():
            print(x)
            if x == "k":
                check1 = True
            elif x == "$":
                check1 = True
            elif x == "£":
                check1 = True
        if check1 and check2: #both success so must be correct
            print("Is not a dm and includes a price")
            split_message = message.content.split(" ")
            price = None
            for x in split_message:
                if "$" in x:
                    #if "/" not in x:
                        price = x
                elif "£" in x:
                    #if "/" not in x:
                        price = x
                elif "k" in x:
                    #if "/" not in x:
                        price = x
```

Update:

```
if check1 and check2: #both success so must be correct
            print("Is not a dm and includes a price")
            split_message = message.content.split(" ")
            messageNoBold = message.content.replace('**','')
            price = None
            thePrice = re.findall("\d+(\.\d+)?[kK]", split_message)
            for x in thePrice:
                
                if "$" in x:
   
                        price = x
                        
                elif "£" in x:
                    
                        price = x
                        
                elif "k" in x:
                    
                        price = x
                        
            print(price)
```

returns -

```
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: You might try the regular expression `\d+(\.\d+)?[kK]`.

Comment: Where would I put that? sorry I am fairly new to coding.

Comment: @Abion47 your regex pattern doesn't work for example title "Taking 2.1k for my product"

Comment: @Ahmet [It works perfectly fine](https://regex101.com/r/v6bOD4/1).

Comment: @Abion47 I updated the post could you check if I did it correctly? Im certain its wrong.

Comment: @Lukemul69 `re.findall` want's a string or byte object, but `split_message` is a list. You don't need to split it before passing it to the regex, it will search the entire string. Just pass in `message.content`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with regex:

```
re.findall("\d+(\.\d+)?[kK]", text)
```

*Thanks Abion47*

Comment: Thank you, where in the code would I put this? I am fairly new to coding in python.

Comment: @Lukemul69 just change 'text' to the message.content. This function will return all occurrences.

Comment: I just tried this and thought it was working until the word "Bank" came through as a price

Comment: I updated the post could you see if I did it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

A solution if you dont want to use regex:

```
your_str = "Taking $2.1k for my product"
if any([i.endswith('k') and not i[:-1].isalpha() for i in your_str.split()]):
    print("Is not a dm and includes a price")
    do_stuff_you_wanna_do_incase_its_a_price()
```

Comment: Sorry where on the script would I put that? Im not great at python

Comment: Where Original if is. It gets into if and only if string contains a numeric price followed by 'k'